# Manifolds with positive sectional curvature almost everywhere

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

On the paper 
[Manifolds with positive sectional curvature almost everywhere](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002220100190)

Burkhard Wilking asks the following (Question $2$ pg. 121):

> Let $(M^n,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with non--negative sectional curvature. Assume that there is an open subset $U\subset M$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g$ has positive sectional curvature on $M\setminus U$. Does $M$ admit a Riemannian metric of positive sectional curvature?

I would like to know if this question is already answered on the literature in its full generality or with symmetry assumptions, e.g, on the presence of an isometric and effective action by a Lie group.

Comment: Did you ask the author of the paper?

Comment: @Truong, I don't think I have enough reputation to ask it to him

Comment: Ask your advisor if you have.